# Eilenberg MacLane space with nonzero homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Does there exists an abelian group $G$ such that $H_2(K(G,1);\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$? If so, what is an example of such a group $G$?

The question is motivated by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773340/higher-homology-group-of-eilenberg-maclane-space-is-trivial?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torus $T^2$ is a $K(\Bbb Z^2,1)$ with nonzero second homology, since it is an orientable 2-manifold.

Answer (score 2):

The singular homology of the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(G,1)$
is isomorphic to group homology
$$H_n(K(G,1);\Bbb Z)\cong H_n(G;\Bbb Z).$$
[Joyner's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0549) on computational group (co)homology theory gives
as an example
$$H_2(A_5;\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: But $A_5$ isn't abelian.

Comment: Ouch! Nice example anyway!

Answer (score 2):

For $G = \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$, the group $H_2(K(G, 1)) = H_2(G)$ contains a term $H_1(\mathbb{Z}_n)^{\otimes 2}\not= 0$ by the Kunneth formula.  If you don't require that $G$ is finite, just take $G = \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $K(G, 1) = T^n$ for $n\geq 2$.